# Canvas в качестве панели ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

есть код xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lvItems,Converter={StaticResource TextToTextBlockConverter}}" Name="lb">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

(не спрашивайте, почему контролы создаю в конвертере) :)

и конвертер

```
public class TextToTextBlockConverter : IValueConverter
{
    int top = 0;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strs = value as List<string>;
        var tbs = new List<TextBlock>();
        foreach (var str in strs)
        {
            var tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = str;
            tbs.Add(tb);
            Canvas.SetTop(tb, top);
            top = top + 100;
        }


        return tbs;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Все нормально, каждый итем на 100 ниже предыдущего. Но если я меняю `ItemsControl` на `ListBox`, то все элементы встают в положение `(0, 0)`

почему так?

Дополнения:

Путем исследования визуального дерева обнаружил, что Текстовые боксы заворачиваются в `ListBoxItem`, поэтому расширения `Canvas` на них уже не действуют, потому что внутри канвы лежат обертки. Пока не придумал, как мне это знание использовать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно назначить значение свойству ItemContainerStyle у ListBox. По умолчанию это и есть ListBoxItem.
Или же просто создать стиль для ListBoxItem и добавить его в ресурсы ListBox или же всего приложения.

Чтобы у вас всё уложилось в голове, прочитайте статью: http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/08/05/itemscontrol-n-is-for-natural-user-interface/

Когда я делал свой первый кастомный ItemsControl именно она расставила всё по местам в моей голове